# Julia For-Loop Scoping- How do I overwrite values of a DataFrame and have the new values persist to the next iteration?

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, scope, julia

My code looks something like this:

```
using DataFrames

# Simulation
out0   = Vector[];
nsim   = Int(1e1);

## Initialize player parameters to random integers between 1 and 100
params = rand(1:100, (5,4));
params = DataFrame(params, :auto);
params.player_id = 1:nrow(params);
params = params[!, [5; 1:4]];

for n in 1:nsim

    # Aggregate current simulation results
    df_vector = DataFrame[];
    push!(df_vector, params);

    # Add current results to final
    push!(out0, df_vector);
    
    # Update parameters
    params[!, 2:5] = max.(min.(params[!, 2:5] .+ rand(-2:2, 5, 4), 100), 0);
    # params = max.(min.(params .+ rand(-2:2, 5, 4), 100), 0);

end
```

If I leave out the "playerID" column and simply overwrite params then it works as expected. The line overwriting columns 2:5 does work, but when I check out0 it is all the same values for params. Further, this repeated DataFrame is the *last* one generated.

Comment: Maybe leave `df_vector = DataFrame[];` outside loop?

Comment: @DanGetz I left out the actual simulation, since it is not important to understanding why I got this behavior. But that df_vector contains various results for each iteration, so it is supposed to be overwritten. Then out0 is the log of what happened each iteration.

Comment: OK, the reason all the `out0` entries are the same, is because they are pushed with the same `params` DataFrame. The `params` has only one memory area, and a variable pointing to this memory is `push!`ed several times. Thus a change in one, changes the others. See: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables/#man-assignment-expressions

Comment: @DanGetz Thanks! This seems to explain it. Is there a simple way to accomplish overwriting some of the columns of params then storing each iteration in out0? Ie, make that line an assignment rather than mutation.

Comment: The code as it stands in the question feels too complex to me (too many structures within structures). The quick and simple way to avoid using the same `params` is to replace `push!(df_vector, params)` with `push!(df_vector, copy(params))`

Comment: @DanGetz Understood. This is essentially my first julia code so I am still trying to do something like I would in R. Ie, store the results in a named nested list so I can easily examine what is going on.